# Get user password in php when using basic authentication

Tags: php, basic-authentication

I want to use basic authentication in php (I use Apache as server but I want to authenticate by myself). So, I set a role to the session when the user has done the login. If the role is empty, I will ask the authentication with the code that I found in [php auth](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/features.http-auth.php). I do

```
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
exit;
```

In Apache no authentication is required, only by my php code.

As far as I understood, I should get something like `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`, but if I print the `$_SERVER` variable, these attributes are not there.

I went through this [link](https://devhacksandgoodies.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/apache-pass-authorization-header-to-phps-_serverhttp_authorization/), and I get the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` variable if I set

> SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

as they suggest, but it is empty (honestly I expected it not to work, because that is something I do in my code, not something done by apache).

Well, at the end, how can I get the username:password of basic authentication using only php code, without Apache configuration? It can not be so difficult, am I lost in a glass of water?

Thanks everyone

**EDIT:**
Solution found:
I am new to php and maybe I did some stupid error.

Basically, my pseudo code was:

```
check_auth_variables_in_SERVER_and_set_role()
if ( still_no_role )
{
    set header for login
    exit # it will ask login
}
```

Now I changed to:

```
if ( no PHP_AUTH_USER and other variables in SERVER)
{
    set header for login
    exit # it will ask login
}

check_auth_variables_in_SERVER_and_set_role()

if ( still_no_role )
{
    echo "Login failed";
    exit;
}
```

Could you explain in details the difference in the two structures of the code?
I think I was a bit confused about the workflow

Thanks everyone

Comment: try loooking here https://xneelo.co.za/help-centre/website/php_auth-fastcgi/

Comment: Thanks delboy, I went also through that link but didn't help. I found the solution anyway. Check the EDIT of my question.

Comment: the first example in the docs is for checking an exiting header (good for api's). you need to be looking at the second/third examples if your going to be handling logging in from the prompt, also there is so many comments with a ton of examples.